# How better check Request.QueryString string parameter for null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string

I need explanations.. I using C#.NET to web applications, I always write:

```
 string val = Request.QueryString["foo"];
```

and then

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
```

What's the difference:

```
string val = Request.QueryString["foo"];
```

I was advised to do:

```
string val = Request.QueryString["foo"] as string;
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first is better:

```
string val = Request.QueryString["foo"];
```

The second version returns `null` if the result of the call is not a string, but you know it *always* will be a string because the `QueryString` member has type `NameValueCollection`. The indexer is defined to return a `string`:

```
public class NameValueCollection : NameObjectCollectionBase
{
    // ...
    public string this[string name] { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `as string` is redundant as `Request.QueryString["foo"]` already is a string. (So there is no other difference than the second makes you look like you don't know your framework ;-) )